# Не редактируется xml

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xml, mobile-development

такая проблема, не могу добавить что-либо на экран (какие-либо элементы: кнопки, текстовые поля и т.д.). Можете подсказать, в чем проблема и как ее решить?[image: вот тут не могу добавить ничего]

Comment: Либо скачайте все необходимые библиотеки к используемому апи (я так полагаю апи 28), либо целевой апи сделайте 27 и подключенные библиотеки сделайте версии 27.1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зайдите в файл `styles.xml` и в контейнере с именем `"AppTheme"` поставьте `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"`

**example:**

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!

Comment: Я только не знаю насколько это правильно, так делать. Скорее это "ультра-хак"

Comment: а иначе можно как-то решить эту проблему или вообще ее избежать при создание проекта?